# Delphi XE5 Android TButton colors

Tags: delphi, button, colors, firemonkey

I need change color of 50 buttons in one form.
Every button another color and color want to set by code(no design editor).

It is firemonkey mobile application.

Comment: What keeps you from doing this, what is your question? What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 2):

By my opinion, without making your own button that doesn't use FMX styles completely (which would break multiplatform compatibility if you are looking forward to support multiple platforms with their native styles), you may apply some filter on top of each of those buttons but on some styles this may cause the text not to be visible, implementing your own filter might get you the desired result:

```
Effect:=TFillRGBEffect.Create(Self);
Effect.Color:=$80FF0000;
Effect.Parent:=SomeButton;
```

Another way would be to take advantage of `TColorButton` with `TText` on top of it, but this way the entire button won't be filled with your color, but you can modify default/custom style for each platform in order to get what you need (this indeed needs to be done in the designer but you would have to create just one style for each platform you need to support and not 50 for each button):

```
Button:=TColorButton.Create(Self);
Button.Color:=$80FF0000;
Text:=TText.Create(Button);
Text.Parent:=Button;
Text.Align:=TAlignLayout.alClient;
Text.Text:='Hello';
Text.HitTest:=false;
Button.ClipChildren:=true;
Button.Parent:=Self;
```